# Drawing WMS layer with Attribute-Based Dynamic SLD to HTML Canvas?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, html5

I'm working on an app using GeoServer and OpenLayers 2.13.1. I have several WMS layers and I need to export whatever in my openlayers map div as an image. After researching, I found this blog: http://blogs.edina.ac.uk/category/openlayers-html5-canvas/ which is working fine (exporting my layers as an image).

However, my wms layer also has dynamic sld functionality (using SLD_BODY). The problem shows up when I use attribute-based sld: it wasn't drawn on the canvas. It only works when I use non-attribute-based sld.

Did I miss something here?

This is how I call the wms layer:

```
wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(layer_name,
    WMSServiceURL, {
        layers: "bappeko:"+map_name, 
        styles: null,
        transparent: true,
        format: "image/jpeg"
    },{
        ratio: 1,
        singleTile: true,
        tileOptions: {maxGetUrlLength: 2048},
        buffer: 0,
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:32749")
    }
);
map.addLayer(wms);
```

This is JS function I used to export:

```
function exportMap() {
var mapcanvasDiv = null ;
var mapDiv = document.getElementById("mapdiv") ;

if (mapcanvasDiv === null) {              
    var canvasElement = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvasElement.id = "mapcvs";
    mapcanvasDiv = document.getElementById("mapcanvas");
    mapcanvasDiv.appendChild(canvasElement) ;

    canvasElement.width = mapDiv.clientWidth ;
    canvasElement.height = mapDiv.clientHeight ;
}

var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("mapcvs");
var mapContainer = document.getElementById("OpenLayers_Map_2_OpenLayers_Container");

if (mapCanvas !== null) {
    var ctx = mapCanvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, mapCanvas.width, mapCanvas.height);

    var olLayersDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("olLayerDiv");
    var olLayers = map.layers;

    for (var i=0; i<olLayersDiv.length; i++){
        //ONLY EXPORT VISIBLE LAYERS
        if (olLayers[i].visibility == true) {
            var layertiles = olLayersDiv[i].getElementsByClassName("olTileImage");
            for(var j=0; j<layertiles.length; j++) {
                var tileImg = layertiles[j];
                var offsetLeft = tileImg.offsetLeft;
                var offsetTop = tileImg.offsetTop;
                var left = Number(mapContainer.style.left.slice(0, mapContainer.style.left.indexOf("p")));
                var top = Number(mapContainer.style.top.slice(0, mapContainer.style.top.indexOf("p")));
                ctx.drawImage(tileImg, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    var dataUrl = mapCanvas.toDataURL();
    window.open(dataUrl, "toDataURL() image", "width=600, height=360");
}
```

This is how I set my dynamic SLD (the SLD is created dynamically by PHP script via Ajax) in JS:

```
l = map.getLayersByName(layer_name)[0];
l.mergeNewParams({sld_body: sld, styles: null});
```

---

I guess I've found the culprit: It seems that my PHP-created SLD is way too long even when I've set `tileOptions: {maxGetUrlLength: 2048}` because I use many `<ogc:Filter>` for my Attribute-Based SLD.

Here's what I've tried: I put my SLD in a text file and load it using `SLD: some_url/text.sld` param, instead of putting it straight to SLD_BODY like I did before. But another error happens, the map won't load (pink image) and I'm getting this error `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type application/vnd.ogc.se_xml: http://localhost/geoserver/wms?...` Seems like the WMS request doesn't return an image but XML.

Comment: If you are triggering off the Layer Loadend Event and copying to the Canvas, it should not matter if you have attribute based SLD, it is still just a WMS call! Are you sure your attribute SLD WMS calls are working and returning images?

Comment: Hi, @MarkC Yes, that's what I thought so. The SLD is working fine, I know that from seeing the correct style applied on my map. It's just don't show up on the canvas, thus, I can't export that layer to an image (the other layers with non-attribute based SLD is working fine though).

Comment: It will help if you modify your question and post your code so we can see how it is implemented ..

Comment: Hi @MarkC I've posted the code on the post above. :D

Comment: It looks Ok, but you have not included the OL Code. CORS could be an issue, possibly your layers are not loaded properly before you try and export them to to Canvas, maybe the visible property is set to false when this routine executes. I wonder if OL WMS handles the Dynamic SLD differently than a normal layer ..

Comment: Hi, @MarkC I've added the OL Code I used to call the WMS. Btw, I've just realized that it's drawn fine on canvas if I set the attribute-based style as the map's default style from the Geoserver web admin (not from setting the sld_body property). So what I'm gonna try now is saving the sld created to a text file, save it to temp folder, and call the url by setting the sld property, instead of sld_body. I'll update the result later.

Comment: I was just wondering why you use `for (var i=0; i<olLayersDiv.length; i++)`instead of `for (var i=0; i<olLayers.length; i++)`

Comment: Hi @MarkC, it seems that OL is creating a div related to a layer when the layer is added. e.g. I have a wms layer above, then I debug: console.log(wms.div); I'll get the DOM Element of the div. And all the divs have the same class name, "olLayerDiv". So it doesn't matter whether I use olLayersDiv.length or olLayers.length in my case, since both arrays returning the same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did, and it finally works.

First, I created a sld file and saved it to the some folder in PHP:

```
$sld = "sld_here..";
$temp_link = sys_get_temp_dir()."/";

$tmpfname = tempnam($temp_link, $map_name);
file_put_contents($tmpfname, $sld);

echo $tmpfname;
```

Then the file url is passed to JS using AJAX and set it to the layer using `SLD` param:

```
l = map.getLayersByName("layer_name")[0];

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "text",
    url: "SLDCreator.php",
    data: {
        //Sending what is required to create a valid SLD file
        map_name: "map_name",
        data: "some sld parameters here"
    },
    success: function(sld) {
        //Set the SLD to the layer
        l.mergeNewParams({sld: "file:///"+sld});
    }
});
```

the `file:///` will works on localhost. When online, you need to save it to a folder (e.g. `sld/`) and call it from `http_your_domain/sld/your_sld_file`.

So this way, I don't need to send my complete sld (which can be very-very long when we use many filters). I just need to send the url of sld file created which is much shorter.